# Application.properties file unload with SpringBoot

Tags: spring, maven, properties, spring-boot

I actually use spring for a back-end server. I also use SpringBoot for the configuration of all this.

I also need to connect this server to a local database, for now. So I use an application.properties's file. This file is located in `src/main/resources`

```
#Datasource
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/base_temp
spring.datasource.username: postgres
spring.datasource.password: password
spring.datasource.driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver

#Jpa
jpa.database: POSTGRESQL
jpa.show-sql: true  
jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create
jpa.hibernate.dialect: PostgreSQLDialect
jpa.hibernate.namingStrategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

No matter what I put, in spring.datasource.password, I don't have any error in console so I guess the file isn't load.

To solve this I've try to include this in my pom.xml

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>application.properties</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

I've also try the @PropertySource or create the  Datasource's @Bean myself :

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/base_temp");
    dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");
    return dataSource;
}
```

But in every cases this back-end was enable to get Data from the database. I don't really know how to use SpringBoot and right know, I'm not incapable to see what's rong with my configuration.

There is also how I launch this :

```
   /**
     * This is the Spring-Boot application launcher
     *
     */
    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @EnableJpaRepositories
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "XXX.be" })
    @EntityScan(basePackages = { "XXX.be.model" })
    public class Launcher extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Launcher.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
            SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Launcher.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
                new ServletContainer(), "/pige/*");
        registration.addInitParameter(
                ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS,
                ApplicationConfiguration.class.getName());
        return registration;
    }


    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory() {
        final JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory = new JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected JettyEmbeddedServletContainer getJettyEmbeddedServletContainer(
                    Server server) {
                return new JettyEmbeddedServletContainer(server);
            }
        };
        jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory
                .addServerCustomizers(new JettyConfigurer());
        return jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DozerBeanMapper dozerBean() {
        DozerBeanMapper dozerBean = new DozerBeanMapper();
        return dozerBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your file located? How do you start your aplication... Do you have the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` configured in your maven pom?

Comment: The file is located in src/main/resrouces, I forgot to write it, i'll edit. I don't forget `srping-boot-maven-plugin` in my pom. And I launch the application with this : `SpringApplication.run(Launcher.class, args);` into a Launcher class who configure some @Bean

Comment: Post your class that launches the application.

Comment: I was editing the post, it's now done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it was a simple compatibility mistake between 2 artifacts in pom.xml